# How to align prose ``from here until further notice''

Tags: align, environments

I am writing a code user guide with some friends at uni for a project we are working on, and would like to wrap up the following type of thing into an environment. Currently our approach is somewhat unsophisticated:

```
{\textcolor{purple}{{\textbf{\url{ClassName}}}}}

\textcolor{brown}{\hspace{2em} \url{type}} \url{ firstMethodName}: An easy to describe function

\textcolor{brown}{\hspace{2em} \url{type}} \url{ secondMethodName}: Some long description which wraps around onto the next line because it is too long for one line
```

which results in the following output:

[image: Current Output]

There are a couple of problems:

1. The beginning of the descriptions (here "An easy..." and "Some long..." would ideally be at the same indent level - currently this is a bit jarring)
2. The long description shown wraps onto the next line in line with the surrounding prose, which looks awful. Is there a way to say something like *any prose from here should start from this indent level until further notice* such that "line because it is too long for one line" would line up with "Some long description"?

Thanks for reading! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Do these lines starting with `type` have be indented w.r.t.   `className`?

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we were thinking the 'type' declaration would be one indent level deeper than the className definition

Comment: I guess it could be done simply with some `tabularx`

Comment: @Bernard - An excellent guess. :-)

Comment: @Mico: Do we share the same crystal ball? :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a `tabularx`-based solution. The first two columns are of types `r` and `l`, respectively, and the third is of type `X`, which means that it takes up as much space as possible while allowing automatic line wrapping.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor,tabularx,ragged2e,url}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}
\noindent\textcolor{red}{Before:}\strut\hrule\smallskip\noindent
{\textcolor{purple}{{\textbf{\url{ClassName}}}}}

\textcolor{brown}{\hspace{2em} \url{type}} \url{ firstMethodName}: An easy to describe function

\textcolor{brown}{\hspace{2em} \url{type}} \url{ secondMethodName}: Some long description which wraps around onto the next line because it is too long for one line


\bigskip
\noindent\textcolor{red}{After:}\strut\hrule\smallskip\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{\ttfamily}r >{\ttfamily}l L @{}}
\color{purple}\textbf{ClassName} \\
\color{brown}type & firstMethodName & An easy to describe function\\[0.5ex]
\color{brown}type & secondMethodName & Some long description which wraps around onto the next line because it is too long for one line \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Is there a way to make the columns a fixed size? When a few of these appear on a page and the column size is chosen differently for each environment it looks quite jarring

Comment: @mcindoe - You asked, "Is there a way to make the columns a fixed size?* Just replace (a) `>{\ttfamily}r` with `>{\ttfamily\raggedleft}p{<some width>}` and (b) `>{\ttfamily}l` with `>{\ttfamily}p{<some other width>}`.